# Vuejs sending multiple get requests

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuex

I am making a Vuejs post request when component is mounted (using Vuex actually), and it all looks good. But when I inspect the console under network tab, I see that the `get` request is actually sent to the backend multiple times when the page loads. Is this normal? This is my request (using axios)

```
// component calling Store action
methods: {
  ...mapActions({
       fetchItems: 'items/fetchCart' 
  }),
},

mounted(){
   this.fetchItems();
}
```

Now in Axios, this is the action sent to the backend

```
const actions = {
  fetchItems({commit}){
    return axios.get('/api/items').then((response) => {
        // commit a mutation to set the items in the state
        commit('SET_ITEMS', response.data)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
},
}
```

So this fetches the items just fine and populates the store, but I see from the network tab of my browser that this request is actually sent multiple times (5 times), which kind of affects some of my other logic in the backend.

I am using `Laravel5.4` as the backend BTW.

Comment: How often is the component mounted? Sounds like 5 times. How is it used?

Comment: It is mounted with an inline template in Laravel, but only once actually

Comment: Try just moving the API call to `created`.

Comment: Well..but up to 5 times...sounds strange right?

Comment: Not really, because I don't know anything about the component other than what is posted. Components are mounted all the time for different reasons. Maybe the component is destroyed for some reason and mounted again. Maybe the view is changing. There's just not enough info to go on.

Comment: O...actually I see...you were right...my bad. It was being mounted in different partials on the same page, so mounted multiple times. I removed it from the partials and it only sends one request...thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Sounds good :) Glad to hear you got it sorted.